# Install vmware under WUBI Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wubi

I had installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my win 7 64bit using WUBI with success.
but here i have a big problem to install vmware 9.0.0 or vmware 8.1.0 under Ubuntu 12.04, always in get crashed to complete the vmware installation so please let me know the steps and the versions which i can follow to install vmware on "Ubuntu 12.04"

Comment: What's the specific problem that happens when you try to install VMware?

Comment: Ubuntu get crashed and can't start again i tried to make fsck and recover it but its fully crashed so i tried several times with diffrent version of Vmware 9.0.0 and 8.1.0 and both get crashed

Comment: This is still very vague. What do you mean by "get crashed"? What happens when you try to start it again?

Answer (score 0):

vm-vare has problems on Ubuntu in some cases. Try virtual-box.
I am using virtual-box on WUBI 11.10 and it works perfectly.